# How to get the text from a QLineEdit widget and use it in a State Machine?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am trying to create a program that waits for the user to input something into a line edit widget, and when they hit enter, I want to compare the value to some predefined one (for example "1"). The problem I seem to be having is that I cannot find a way to make this work with the QStateMachine. At the moment, it will wait for the user to press enter and it just switches over to the next state, but I want it to only go to the next state if the input is "1". Here is the code I am using and thank you for any help that you can offer.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(someSlot()));
    setupStateMachine();
}

...

void MainWindow::setupStateMachine()
{
    QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(this);
    QState *s1 = new QState();
    QState *s2 = new QState();
    QState *s3 = new QState();

    s1->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", readFile("intro.txt"));
    s2->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "In state s2");
    s3->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "In state s3");

    s1->addTransition(this, SIGNAL(editing()), s2);
    s2->addTransition(this->ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), s3);
    s3->addTransition(this->ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), s1);

    machine->addState(s1);
    machine->addState(s2);
    machine->addState(s3);
    machine->setInitialState(s1);

    machine->start();

    qDebug() << "State Machine Created";
}

...

void MainWindow::someSlot()
{
    if(ui->lineEdit->text() == "1")
    {
        emit editing();
    }
}
```

In the header file:

```
{
...
signals:
    void editing();
...
private slots:
    void someSlot();
...
};
```

PS: I realize that the signal does not do what I want, but I can't figure out which signal to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can connect `editingFinished` to your own slot. In that slot, check if the input is "1". if so, emit a new signal you pass into `addTransition` instead of `editingFinished`

To add a signal to a class, change the class like this (make sure there is a `Q_OBJECT` declared at the very top of the class):

```
signals:
    void mySignalName();
```

Signals are guaranteed protected. You don't write the body of the function. That's what MOC does. So, when you want to call the signal in your class, just call:

```
emit mySignalName();
```

emit is just for code documentation. It's #defined to nothing. MOC will generate the body of `mySignalName` and boil down to calls to the slots you connect it to using QObject::connect.

To add a new slot to your class, add this:

```
private slots:
    void mySlotName();
```

Note that you will have to write the body of a slot.

```
void MainWindow::mySlotName()
{
    if(myLineEdit->text() == "1")
        emit mySignalName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, should I just write a function, add it to the signals in the header and then emit a signal? I tried to do this but how exactly do I emit a signal from a function?

Comment: Okay I tried your code and it almost works, I just have a couple questions. Should I be doing connect in the constructor of mainwindow.cpp? And why does emit need to be in the slot? Also I updated my question with my current code. It compiles with no errors but still does not work.

Comment: Yes, you should connect in the constructor so you're sure it only happens once. Although that's not a restriction. You can connect/disconnect anywhere. Emitting a signal is just a function call. You can emit them anywhere in your class. If you didn't emit from the slot as I described... where would you emit from? Don't over think it. Signals and slots are just functions. The only thing special is that you don't implement a signal your self, Qt generates the code for the signal at compile time.

Comment: You still need to change the signal passed to addTransition to your new signal

Comment: and you need to connect editingFinished to your new slot instead of passing it to addTransition

Comment: You're trying to set up a chain of events. when the editing finishes, call your slot. when your slot is called, check the text. if the text is "1", emit your signal. That signal emitted will cause the state to change